# Has the double-slit experiment been performed with animals as the observers?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, double-slit-experiment, observers, wavefunction-collapse

As the title says, has the double-slit experiment been performed with animals (not humans) as the observers? If yes, which animal was used and what was the result?

Comment: What "quantum uncertainty experiment"?

Comment: I think this is related to consciousness causes collapse ideas, isn't it?

Comment: The double-slit.

Comment: I just showed my dog a picture of the interference pattern from a double slit experiment. The result was that he appeared to be unimpressed.

Answer (score 2):

OK, Socks and Rover, tell us what you saw.

Or more seriously, "observation" by non-sentient machines happens all the time. Indeed, in some case you don't even have to record the observation, just enable it. See for instance [Phys. Rev. Lett. 75 3783 1995](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.75.3783) AKA http://chapmanlabs.gatech.edu/papers/scattering_ifm_prl95.pdf. This paper actually covers a multi-slit experiment: it is exactly what you've asked about, except that the observation isn't even recorded. Run the laser in a location where it can resolve the slit passed and the interference pattern goes away. Don't run the laser or do so in a place where it can't resolve the slit and the pattern is present.

There is no mind needed, and never has been. In all seriousness, that was the whole point of the cat-in-a-box experiment and Wigner's extension: that whatever "collapse" is and however it happens *it must be a consistent process*.

Comment: I sort of agree, but you've got the history about Wigner's friend all wrong. See wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner's_friend#Consciousness_and_measurement

Comment: "Wigner designed the experiment to illustrate his belief that consciousness is necessary to the quantum mechanical measurement process"

Comment: Hmmm ... well, shows you what I know. But the data doesn't support him.

Comment: Random footnote: I've posted this link three times in the last two weeks. I may have to give it a rest.

Comment: "Wigner's friend" was a gedanken-experiment; it didn't involve any experimental data. I don't follow how any experiment disproves the hypothesis that consciousness causes collapse. How do you know it wasn't in a superposition before someone looked at it?

Comment: hmm, but in your answer, you mean that they moved the light source (laser) to collapse/revive the wave pattern. The original experiment only _observed_ it to collapse it. The nature of experiment has changed too much from one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to train animals to distinguish between the alternative fringe patterns resulting from a double-slit configuration. The effect has been shown repeatedly by purely mechanical (as opposed to psychological) means. If you'll look at the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment) you'll see pictures of the fringe patterns, and there is no reason to believe that conscious observation was involved. As a matter of fact, if the photographs were taken by an SLR, the fringes were invisible to the photographer during the exposure due to mirror motion.

So no, no animals have been used to collapse the wave function - it happens all by itself.

Or do you credit photographic media (film or CCD/CMOS sensors) with intelligence?

Comment: How do you know you didn't cause the collapse when you looked at the results from a machine? The machine could have been in a superposition? Couldn't it?

Answer (score -1):

I'll confess that consciousness causes collapse is one of the interpretations of QM with which I'm unfamiliar. I think, though, it is quite relevant to your question: you want to replace conscious observers, i.e. humans, whatever conscious means, with animals, which presumably aren't conscious. By doing so, you wish to test the hypothesis that consciousness causes collapse.

For what it's worth, I presume unconscious living things (bacteria, insects etc) and objects (tables, chairs etc) were present in almost every experiment in QM. They might have "seen" the results prior to a human.

I'm not sure how any such an experiment, however, could test the consciousness causes collapse idea, in a manner that was satisfactory for a conscious human. How would we know that the state was in an collapsed or uncollapsed superposition prior to the first human observing it?

Suppose I trained my pet dog to perform experiments involving collapse. Perhaps he returns to me and says,

> "The wave-function collapsed! When I performed a which way experiment,
>   I found the electron went through the LHS!"

But the collapse might have only happened once I became cognisant of the dog's return - he might have been in a superposition of LHS and RHS prior to that, which my consciousness collapsed. I could replace dog with any kind of computer or mechanical device - the same objection occurs. It could collapse at the moment a human reads the result from the computer or sees the digital photograph of a double-slit screen on a camera.

The main objection to consciousness causes collapse, I think, is that it requires an ill-defined notion of consciousness that impacts physical laws. The laws of physics for a system (or algorithm) running "consciousness" change. This "dualism" - that mind and matter are somehow distinct substances obeying different laws - seems quite implausible.

Comment: Apparently, photos of both wave and collapsed states have been taken, but I don't remember the keywords to search for the photos. The circumstances around this wave collapse experiment are unclear from various report/articles, so I am frankly confused too. However, experiments did show that you can collapse it with observation _after_ the fact that the particle has already passed through the slits. So yes, depending on the setup, it may be hard to prove using another animal.